# Live search on first, middle and last name

Tags: jquery, mysql

I want to do a live search based upon a person full name(first, middle and last). If a person search "John lewis Morris" the query should return the desire results for "John lewis Morris".

Now the middle name field is not required in my database. So, a person can have a first name and last name while another person can have a first, middle and last name.
This is my query:

```
"Select * form person where CONCAT(first,' ',middle,' ',last) LIKE $_POST['searchValue']  OR first LIKE $_POST['searchValue'] OR middle LIKE $_POST['searchValue'] OR last $_POST['searchValue']";
```

What happens is that when I search by first name/middle name/last name only it returns records available. But if I search by first and last(John Doe) it returns nothing. If I also search by first, middle and last(John Amos Doe) it returns nothing.

I have this feeling that the problem is coming from my query. How do I get this working. I using JQuery Ajax function to live search. If more explanation is needed please let me know.

**NOTE**: Before I was searching only by first and last name and it works perfectly.
This was my query then:

```
 "Select * form person where CONCAT(first,' ',middle,' ',last) LIKE $_POST['searchValue']";
```

Comment: SQL Injection warning.

Comment: @shmosel thanks for that. Will handle it later, but need this to work now.

Comment: Which record should be returned when the `searchValue` is `John Doe` and the table contains both: `John Doe` and `John Amos Doe`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't include that but contact number and adderss should be return

Comment: Well, I think you'd probably want to change your condition as: `.... WHERE (CONCAT(first,' ',middle,' ',last) LIKE $_POST['searchValue']) OR (CONCAT(first,' ',last) LIKE $_POST['searchValue']) `. However, the previous question was about two separate records in the table with similar names. The condition given here would select both `John Doe` and `John Amos Doe`. But again, it's not very clear whether you want `searchValue` to contain an exact string or an approximate string. If it's an exact string, it might be better to use `=` instead of `LIKE`. Also, please be wary of SQL Injection Attacks